# How can I show an output in r by a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Im trying to show the output of my code depending by a condition that its `print.condition(pregunta_menos < 12347)` but it only displays an error, How can I display minimum sum in the output?

Here's part of my code:

```
pregunta_menos <- colSums(!is.na(df))

as.data.table(pregunta_menos,keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

I need to print `("The Minimum column is:" )`

Comment: Perhaps `which.min(pregunta_menos)`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right! Thank you so much, But the only problem its that its not counting the NA, how can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean it is not counting NA? For example, `which.min(c(2, 1, NA))` returns `2`, which is the index of integer `1`. This vector contains NA, so NA is not affecting the result.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I dont know why I count it bad, but yeah is working, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)

#some dummy data
(df <- 
    paste0('x', 1:5) %>% 
    map_dfc(~ tibble('{.x}' := rnorm(5))))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>       x1     x2     x3      x4     x5
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  0.235  0.140 -0.174 -1.57    0.362
#> 2 -0.331 -1.50  -0.407 -0.0859  0.347
#> 3 -0.312 -1.01   1.85  -0.359   0.190
#> 4 -2.30  -0.948  0.394 -1.19   -0.160
#> 5 -0.171 -0.494  0.798  0.364   0.327

min_col <- 
  df %>% 
  colSums() %>% 
  which.min() %>% 
  names()

paste("The Minimum column is:", min_col)
#> [1] "The Minimum column is: x2"

#Calculate only with numeric columns

nms <- select(df, where(is.numeric)) %>% names()

min_col_numeric_only <- 
df %>% 
  transmute(c_sums = colSums(across(where(is.numeric), ~.)), nms = nms) %>% 
  filter(c_sums == min(c_sums)) %>% 
  pull(nms)

paste("The Minimum column is:", min_col_numeric_only)
#> [1] "The Minimum column is: x2"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. But when I try it in my code I've this error ```Error in colSums(., !is.na(df)) : 'x' must be numeric``` how can I solve it? In the other code I've it runs with ```!is.na```

Comment: It seems that`colSums`  uses every column to perform the sum (even if it's not numeric) so maybe addressing that can help, i've updated the code to do that filtering. Please let me know any doubts. You can use `dput(head(df, 5)` to get the first five rows of `df` if possible.

Comment: It gives me this error ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `c_sums`.
i `c_sums = colSums(across(where(is.numeric), ~.))`.
i `c_sums` must be size 12347 or 1, not 78.```